# Why doesn't Ruby inject return an enumerator?

Tags: ruby, enumerable

I was expecting `Enumerable#inject` would be returning an enumerator like other methods and was passing it a block; but it was throwing error. Tried the following in `pry`:

```
>> numbers = (1..12)
=> 1..12
>> numbers.each_with_index
=> #<Enumerator: ...>
>> numbers.each_with_index.map
=> #<Enumerator: ...>
>> numbers.inject(0)
TypeError: 0 is not a symbol
from (pry):18:in `inject'
```

I was expecting to use it as follows:

```
numbers = (1..12)
block = lambda { |sum, digit| sum + digit }

numbers.inject(0) { |sum, digit| sum + digit } # => 78
numbers.each_with_index.map &block # => [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23]
numbers.inject(0) &block # => 0 is not a symbol (TypeError)
```

Is there some reason for such an implementation?

Comment: Good question. I've not thought about that before. Note there are quite a few `Enumerable` methods that can take a block but do not return an enumerator when not given one.  Others include `count`, `max`, `min`, `minimax`, `none?` `one?`, and `sort`.  I see a commonality in all of them, including `reduce/inject`.

Comment: Thanks @CarySwoveland! I am quite puzzled why they chose to implement it like that. I somehow don't buy the notion that its because there are nearly no use cases for chaining it further. I would suggest consistency might have been better.

Comment: An `Enumerator` is computed one value at a time. You can pull a little bit (by calling `next`) and one value falls out. You pull again, another value falls out. `inject` cannot do that.

Comment: @JörgWMittag wow, thats a perfect explanation. Thanks!

Comment: Four points, Jikku: 1) if `reduce` returned an enumerator and you wanted to sum the values of an array, which totalled `7`, would you return `[7].to_enum`, in which case you'd have to tag on `.next` to retrieve it?   (`7.to_enum` won't work because numeric classes don't have  `each.`) 2) there are other methods you can often use when if you need to return an enumerator, such as `each_with_object` as a replacement for `reduce`; (cont.)

Comment: 3) if `reduce` returns a collection, you can still chain an enumerable method, though there is a temporary array; and 4) we must have faith that the Ruby monks generally do the right thing. Many very sharp, very experienced Rubyists take part in extensive discussions and and debate over proposed changes to the language.  They can be wrong, but for we relative newbies to question their judgement is sort of like telling Yehudi Menuhin, after a few lessons on the violin, that you think the sound could be improved by changing the shape of the instrument. :-)

Comment: @CarySwoveland the last point is good :), I know suggesting something different than their implementation is mostly likely dumb. But, was searching for something like Jorg's answer. Was trying to find the mistake in my assumption trying to let others contradict me :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conceptually, `Enumerator` is a type of collection. `Enumerable#inject` accumulates a value across the members of a collection, it makes little sense for it to return a `Enumerator`.

You can get the job done by changing `numbers.inject(0) &block` to:

```
numbers.inject(0, &block)
```

Comment: Didn't know there was any difference between the two ways to invoke! I was assuming a block if present will be passed in case the method finds one.

Comment: Is it because `inject` definition has block as an argument and others may be using yield to call the block?

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of methods like `inject` is to return some calculated value based on the enumerator. If they always return an enumerator, there would be no meaningful usage. The reason it returns an enumerator when the block is absent is to let you create a new enumerator by modifying the receiver. That should not be the final objective though; you only create an enumerator so that in the end you can calculate something based on that.

Comment: Are you sure about it returning an enumerator when no block is present? E.g.,  `[1,2,3].reduce => LocalJumpError: no block given`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I meant for enumerators.